# User-Defined Function in R with aggregation

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to write a R self-defined function. But I'm relatively new to this part, so I've been struggling with following questions.

1. I want to subset the data where Price == Number and Price != Number, but when I run the function, I get tables with 4 columns and 0 variable.
2. When I want to do aggregate between columns, what I wrote is also wrong.

**My Data**

```
Name1   Name2   Price   Number
  A       F      6        6
  A       D      5        5
  A       E      2        2
  B       F      4        9
  B       D      7        8
  C       F      4        4
  C       E      2        6
```

**My Function**

```
MyFun  <- function(Master_Table, Desired_ColumnA, Desired_ColumnB){

  Table1 <- Master_Table[(Desired_ColumnA== Desired_ColumnB)]
  Table2 <- Master_Table[!(Desired_ColumnA== Desired_ColumnB)]

  Table2$NewCol  = abs(Table2$Desired_ColumnA - Table2$Desired_ColumnB)

  return(Table1)
  return(Table2)

}
```

**Test**

```
MyTest <- MyFun(Data, Price, Number)
```

**Expected Output**

Table1:

```
Name1   Name2   Price   Number
  A       F      6        6
  A       D      5        5
  A       E      2        2
  C       F      4        4
```

Table2 :

```
    Name1   Name2   Price   Number   New
      B       F      4        9       5
      B       D      7        8       1
      C       E      2        6       4
```

It will be the very first step of my whole function. If anyone knows anything about this, please let me know, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you expect as your output?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do in `MyFun`. For example, what's the point of `Table1`? You only use `Table2`. Or am I missing something? You also don't aggregate anywhere. You seem to be calculating an simple absolute difference between two columns, which you can do outside of `MyFun`.

Comment: @Maurits Evers This will be the very first step of the whole function. I just simplified my function above.

Comment: In simplifying your function you clearly made it less clear;-) As @Onyambu said, please provide expected output for you sample data.

Comment: You are correct. I have edited the question. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. A function cannot have multiple `return` statements. If you want to return multiple objects, I would advise putting them in a `list` and returning the `list`.
2. Your subsetting/filtering is not correct. You want to filter *rows* based on a certain condition involving values in two columns. Note the comma in my subsetting commands.
3. You need to pass the column names as character vectors.

How about this?

```
f <- function(df, col1, col2) {

    # Subset data
    df1 <- df[df[col1] == df[col2], ];
    df2 <- df[df[col1] != df[col2], ];

    # Calculate NewCol
    df2["NewCol"] <- abs(df2[col1] - df2[col2]);

    # Return data.frames as list
    return(lst(df1, df2));
}
f(df, "Price", "Number");
#$df1
#  Name1 Name2 Price Number
#1     A     F     6      6
#2     A     D     5      5
#3     A     E     2      2
#6     C     F     4      4
#
#$df2
#  Name1 Name2 Price Number NewCol
#4     B     F     4      9      5
#5     B     D     7      8      1
#7     C     E     2      6      4
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Name1   Name2   Price   Number
  A       F      6        6
  A       D      5        5
  A       E      2        2
  B       F      4        9
  B       D      7        8
  C       F      4        4
  C       E      2        6", header = T)
```

Comment: @YOLO Ah. Sorry:-)

Comment: A lot thanks! I still have some small questions: 1) why shouldn't I use 'normal' data.table form in a function? And which topic would you recommend me do research on for this kind of issue? 2) I tried your code, and I got an error message said: `Error in Ops.data.frame(df[col1], df[col2]) : 
  ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames ` Do you have any idea on what might happen? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try my example? It's fully reproducible and (at least on my side) doesn't throw an error. So there must another issue with your actual data that causes the error, which I cannot comment on. I'm not sure what you mean by *"why shouldn't I use 'normal' data.table form in a function"*. We are working with `data.frame`s here. `data.table`s are different and you don't mention anywhere that you are looking for a `data.table` solution. As far as research goes, these are some very basic R subsetting/filtering operations that any decent R tutorial would cover.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it works perfectly with your data set, but doesn't work for my real data. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @M.zz.M It's not my data set, it's the sample data *you* posted as representative data. As I said, there must be an issue with your bigger data set that you need to identify first.

Comment: Yes I totally agree with you. For the data.table part, it was a typo. What I meant is I can use `df1<- df[which(col1==col2),]` outside of my function, but once I put in inside the function, it returns a data set with 0 variables. Would you know why does this happen by any chance? Thank you!

Comment: @M.zz.M It should be `df1 <- df[which(df[col1] == df[col2]), ]`; but you don't need the `which`.